# Why does this code hang at mentioned place?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

This is a naive example I have coded to study C++ operator overloading. When I execute it, code hangs at the statement c = a + b; and control never reaches `c.display();`

As part of debugging if I put a `cout << ptr << '\n';` in the assignment operator overloaded function it does print out HelloWorld, so string doesn't seem to be malformed.

Why does it hang then? What am I missing ??

```
class mystring
{
    char *ptr;

    public:

   mystring(char *str = "")
   {
      ptr = new char[strlen(str) + 1];
      strcpy(ptr,str);

   } 

   mystring operator +(mystring s)
   {
      char *str = new char[strlen(ptr) + strlen(s.ptr) + 1];//where should this memory be freed
      strcpy(str,ptr);
      strcat(str,s.ptr);
      return mystring(str);
   }

   void operator =(mystring s)
   {
       strcpy(ptr,s.ptr);

      //cout << ptr << '\n'; \\Debug - this prints out HelloWorld but still hangs 
   }

   void display()
   {
       cout << ptr << '\n';
   }

   ~mystring()
   {
      delete [] ptr; 
   }
};

int main()
{
   mystring a="Hello",b="World",c;

  c = a + b;

  c.display();

  getchar();

}
```

**EDIT:** Compiler: MS-Visual C++ 2010 Express / Windows.

Comment: `operator=` does not allocate memory. `operator+` results in allocating twice.

Comment: I'd also add that you should implement a proper copy constructor...

Comment: A memory profiler such as valgrind would have spotted this kind of memory error, use one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you are getting is a memory error. This line:

```
c = a + b;
```

does the following:

```
c.constructor()
c.operator=(a.operator+(b));
```

and your operator= fails to allocate memory

```
void operator =(mystring s)
{
  // ptr is allocated enough memory for "", i.e. one byte
  strcpy(ptr,s.ptr); // copying more than one byte into one byte array
  //cout << ptr << '\n'; // this works, but you've trashed memory with the strcpy
} // stack might be corrupted here, depends where this is, so execution can end up anywhere
```

What you need is:

```
void operator = (mystring &s) // reference!
{
  delete [] ptr;
  ptr = new char [strlen (s.ptr + 1)];
  strcpy (ptr, s.ptr);
}
```

Comment: Or, `tempPtr = new char [strlen (s.ptr + 1)]; strcpy(tempPtr, s.ptr); swap(ptr, tempPtr); delete tempPtr;` to provide [strong exception guarantee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_guarantees).

Comment: @Skizz - thanks. It works but only if I comment out the delete ptr in the destructor function. Any thoughts whyc could this be happening. IS it because ptr is already freed/deleted in operator=() ? Then what is the fix.

Comment: @goldenmean: It's probably because you are copied the `ptr` value somewhere instead of copying the string. Your `operator+` returns the result by value so that is doing a copy and delete, so `ptr` is deleted twice. Try adding a `mystring (const mystring &source)` construct which does the same as `operator =`. You should also set `ptr` to `0` after deleting it so that deleting it again won't cause a problem.

Answer (score 1):

your `operator=` is broken. You aren't properly allocating enough (or any) memory before doing the `strcpy`. This leads to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

> > char *str = new char[strlen(ptr) + strlen(s.ptr) + 1];//where should this memory be freed

Memory freed on destructor.

On operator = you must free the allocated memory and allocate it again

Comment: not really - that particular line you highlighted is in `operator+`, therefore, it must be cleaned up in that function. Second point is correct though...

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Of course, the memory should be freed at the method.

Answer (score 0):

operator = should free the old buffer and then allocate a new one like you do in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The code does not seem to have any obvious issue that would make it block before hitting `c.display()`, but it might *look* like it is doing so.

The operation `cout << ptr << '\n';` does not flush the stream, and that means that the output might be cached until a later time. It might be the case that the whole program has *basically* completed and is waiting for the user to enter a character in `getchar()`.

Try running the code in a debugger or changing the output to `cout << ptr << endl;`.

BTW: You are leaking memory in `operator+`, and should probably take care of it. I know you already asked about the way to do it, you might not have liked (or understood) the solutions that were proposed, but leaving it as it is is no solution.

`operator=` is not ensuring that you have enough space to hold the complete string, which means that you could be triggering Undefined Behavior.